# Is there a way to retrieve the IP Address of a Sender?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

Using a custom receiver is it possible to retrieve the IP address of a specific sender ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot but if you have a custom receiver, you can simply send the ip address from your sender to your receiver using either the customData that is available on a number of existing API calls or use a custom channel/namespace to do it.

Comment: thanks, in fact that's exactly what I'm doing with my sender.. however I was trying to retrieve the remote IP when the sender is for example the Android Chromecast app..